# Как правильно сделать роутинг в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте. При создании сайта изначально были роуты для категорий и подкатегорий:

```
Route::pattern('category', '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+'); // Такие паттерны у всех роутов
Route::get('/{auto}/{country}/', ['as' => 'country', 'uses' => 'AutoController@country']);
Route::get('/{auto}/{country}/archive/', ['as' => 'country.archive', 'uses' => 'AutoController@countryArchive']);
Route::get('/{auto}/{country}/{mark}/', ['as' => 'mark', 'uses' => 'AutoController@mark']);
Route::get('/{auto}/{country}/{mark}/archive/', ['as' => 'mark.archive', 'uses' => 'AutoController@markArchive']);
```

В контроллере если данных нету то вызываю App::abort(404); 
Когда добавил новые роуты, то перестали работать старые (выдавалась 404 ошибка), выше написаны чем прошлые.

```
Route::get('/{category}/', ['as' => 'category.list', 'uses' => 'ArticleCategoriFrontendController@list']); 
Route::get('/{category}/{article_slug}/', ['as' => 'article', 'uses' => 'ArticleCategoriFrontendController@article']);
```

Вот у меня и возник вопрос как этого можно избежать, уже использовал стандартные функции как link_to_route, link_to_action но по прежнему ничего. Код:

```
<?php echo link_to_route('category.list', 'obuchenie', ['obuchenie'] ); ?>
<?php echo link_to_action('ArticleCategoriFrontendController@list', 'obuchenie2', ['obuchenie'] ) ?>
<a href="{{route('category.list',['obuchenie']) }}">obuchenie3</a>
```

Оказывается оно перекидывает на другой роут

```
 Route::get('/{page}/', ['as' => 'page', 'uses' => PageController@page']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваши новые маршруты конфликтуют со старыми:

`'/{category}/'` конфликтует с `'/{page}/'`, а

`'/{category}/{article_slug}/'` с `'/{auto}/{country}/'`.

Чтобы этого избежать, попробуйте добавить статичный сегмент к новым маршрутам, например:

`'/articles/{category}/'`

`'/articles/{category}/{article_slug}/'`

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался с этим.